# Linux KVM if guest is rebooted it will not start, must be manually started

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, virsh

Have an Ubuntu server running KVM:

```
Linux hyperv 4.4.0-109-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 19:52:39 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is running a few VMs which are linux, and one windows vm. After installing a new VM of Windows 2016 server, a problem occurs. The vm (called winstore) may be started by performing the following:

```
virsh start winstore
```

And it comes up fine. If this particular VM is ***restarted*** from within the VM, it will cleanly shutdown, but ***not*** come back up. running

```
virsh list
```

confirms that it has **not** started. In order to start the VM, one must do a

```
virsh start winstore
```

again. This is not the desired behavior, and NOT how the other windows VMs behave (they have the desired behavior, which is they reboot when restarted).

The VM was created a bit differently than normal. These were the steps used to create the VM initially:

create the disk image

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata /mnt/vmstorage/images/winstore.qcow2 1300G
```

get an xml output of what we would do, so we can modify the cdrom attributes

```
virt-install --name winstore --ram 8192 --vcpus=2 --graphics=vnc --network=bridge=br731,model=virtio --disk path=/mnt/vmstorage/images/winstore.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio,cache=none --disk path=/mnt/backups/isos/virtio-win-0.1.126.iso,device=cdrom --cdrom /mnt/backups/isos/SW_DVD9_Win_Server_STD_CORE_2016_64Bit_English_-4_DC_STD_MLF_X21-70526.ISO --os-type=windows --noautoconsole --accelerate --noapic --print-xml > winstore.xml
```

change the order of the cdroms in the xml file:

```
<disk type="file" device="cdrom">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
  <source file="/mnt/backups/isos/virtio-win-0.1.126.iso"/>
  <target dev="hda" bus="ide"/>
  <readonly/>
</disk>
<disk type="file" device="cdrom">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
  <source file="/mnt/backups/isos/SW_DVD9_Win_Server_STD_CORE_2016_64Bit_English_-4_DC_STD_MLF_X21-70526.ISO"/>
  <target dev="hdb" bus="ide"/>
  <readonly/>
```

then it was installed and started by performing the following:

```
virsh create ./winstore.xml 
virsh start winstore
```

after installation, the xml was edited, and the two drives were swapped (hda/hdb) so it will boot from the disk and not cdrom. Then the VM was defined with the following in virsh:

```
virsh define ./winstore.xml
```

Again, the VM seems to work fine now, but it only starts with

```
virsh start winstore
```

Again, ***IF*** the VM is rebooted from within the guest, it will not restart, it will just shutdown. Looking through the logs in 
/var/log/libvirt/qemu/winstore.log there does not seem to be anything out of the ordinary.

Note that the VM appears in a

```
virsh list --all
```

*Yes, I am absolutely, positively sure that I am not clicking on "shutdown" in the windows VM. :)*

Comment: What's in the `<on_reboot>` node in the XML for the VM?

Comment: on_reboot had "destroy". As strange as this sounds, I looked through all of the other xmls, and they all have restart. Parsing the command history, I do not see why it would say "destroy" and not "restart"... but now it restarts.

Answer (score 7):

As per  Michael Hampton comments above, the xml had "destroy" for the `<on_reboot>` node instead of "restart".

Answer (score 4):

As @Michael Hampton and @number9 already suggested, the key is to `virsh edit your_VM` to the following:

```
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
```

As a side note, the VM needs to be rebooted for the changes to take effect.

When using `virt-install`, you can specifiy the events by adding `--events=on_reboot=restart,on_poweroff=restart,on_crash=restart` to your virt-install command.
Keep in mind that on first start, `on_reboot` will still be destroy.

As a more general note, you can use libvirt-guest to configure your machines to boot and shutdown properly with your host.
On CentOS you'd configure `/etc/sysconfig/libvirt-guests` like:

```
ON_BOOT=start # Start the machines with the host
ON_SHUTDOWN=shutdown # Properly shutdown machines with host
PARALLEL_SHUTDOWN=2 # Don't shutdown all machines at the same time, do it 2 by 2 (or else depending on your host and the number of VM)
SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT=600 # Allow a 10 minutes grace period for machines to shutdown properly before destroying them
SYNC_TIME=1 # Sync time with host (useful for suspended machines)
```

Once this is configured, you may enable libvirt-guests with

```
systemctl enable --now libvirt-guests
```

`SYNC_TIME=1` requires guest tools to be installed. You can check that the sync is working with `virsh qemu-agent-command vm_name'{"execute":"guest-set-time"}'` which should return `{"return":{}}`